# Laravel Jetstream v2.16.2 switchable-team click.prevent not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

After composer update Laravel Jetstream from version 1.3 to version 2.16.2 and php from 8.0 to 8.1 click.prevent in jet-switchable-team not working.

navigation.blade.php:
...
 `@foreach (Auth::user()->allTeams() as $team) <x-jet-switchable-team :team="$team"/> @endforeach`
...
vendor/laravel/jetstream/resources/views/components/switchable-team.blade.php:

...
    `<x-dynamic-component :component="$component" href="#" x-on:click.prevent="$root.submit();"> <div class="flex items-center">`
...

Has anyone solved this problem? I thank you in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE

`<x-jet-switchable-team :team="$team" />`

TO

`<x-switchable-team :team="$team" />`

Overall, it will be necessary to modify all `<x-jet-...` to `<x-...`